# How to restructure parent child details in JavaScript, retrieved from database?

Tags: javascript, html, json

I am trying to display parent( Survey ) & child ( Survey participants ) details retrieved from the database ( Salesforce ).

I am using LWC ( Lightning web component ) to display the details.

There is a limitation in lwc that you can't access data from a related object using '__r' ( This means related object  ) directly in HTML component.

Here is my data:

```
[{
"Survey_Participants__r": [
  {
    "Survey__c": "a0c55000002uRCzAAM",
    "Contact__r": {
      "Name": "Soumen Jana",
      "Id": "0035500001CBDnVAAX"
    },
    "Id": "a0d5500000Vv6DpAAJ",
    "Contact__c": "0035500001CBDnVAAX",
    "Status__c": "Sent"
  },
  {
    "Survey__c": "a0c55000002uRCzAAM",
    "Contact__r": {
      "Name": "Dhananjay Dheru",
      "Id": "0035500001CUbS5AAL"
    },
    "Id": "a0d5500000Vv6DqAAJ",
    "Contact__c": "0035500001CUbS5AAL",
    "Status__c": "Sent"
  }
],
"Id": "a0c55000002uRCzAAM",
"Batch_Id__c": "0",
"Status__c": "Sent"}]
```

I need to prepare it something like this :

```
[{
"Survey_Participants__r": [
  {
    "Survey__c": "a0c55000002uRCzAAM",
    "ContactName": "Soumen Jana",
    "Id": "a0d5500000Vv6DpAAJ",
    "Contact__c": "0035500001CBDnVAAX",
    "Status__c": "Sent"
  },
  {
    "Survey__c": "a0c55000002uRCzAAM",
    "ContactName": "Dhananjay Dheru",
    "Id": "a0d5500000Vv6DqAAJ",
    "Contact__c": "0035500001CUbS5AAL",
    "Status__c": "Sent"
  }
],
"Id": "a0c55000002uRCzAAM",
"Batch_Id__c": "0",
"Status__c": "Sent"}]
```

I have tried using two-approach but none of them are working as expected :

Approach 1:
I am trying to use collection.map

```
data.map(record => Object.assign({some data manipulation here},record);
```

It's not allowing to iterate through the nested structure.

Approach 2: nested data.foreach method.

Please let me know how I can fix the above issue.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-gjktut?file=index.ts)

Comment: Thank you for reading through my issue and providing your valuable answer. I am facing some issue when trying to run my code, it's saying ==>   (intermediate value)(intermediate value).map is not a function. Please help me to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I hope you are intending to flat the participant object

```js
let data = [{
  "Survey_Participants__r": [{
      "Survey__c": "a0c55000002uRCzAAM",
      "Contact__r": {
        "Name": "Soumen Jana",
        "Id": "0035500001CBDnVAAX"
      },
      "Id": "a0d5500000Vv6DpAAJ",
      "Contact__c": "0035500001CBDnVAAX",
      "Status__c": "Sent"
    },
    {
      "Survey__c": "a0c55000002uRCzAAM",
      "Contact__r": {
        "Name": "Dhananjay Dheru",
        "Id": "0035500001CUbS5AAL"
      },
      "Id": "a0d5500000Vv6DqAAJ",
      "Contact__c": "0035500001CUbS5AAL",
      "Status__c": "Sent"
    }
  ],
  "Id": "a0c55000002uRCzAAM",
  "Batch_Id__c": "0",
  "Status__c": "Sent"
}];

data.map(childData => {
  childData["Survey_Participants__r"] = childData["Survey_Participants__r"].map(participant => {
      return flatObject(participant);
  });
});

console.log(data);

function flatObject(data) {
  let flatData = {};
  for (key in data) {
    if (data[key].constructor.name === "Object") {
      flatData = { ...flatData,
        ...data[key]
      };
    } else {
      flatData[key] = data[key];
    }
  }
  return flatData;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for reading through my issue and providing your valuable answer. I am facing some issue when trying to run my code, it's saying ==> (intermediate value)(intermediate value).map is not a function. Please help me to resolve it.

Comment: you might be using map function with objects, objects don't have map function but arrays do.
You need to fill in with more details. Above solution not working?